# Multiple forms on a page - textarea value only recognized in the first one using jQuery

Tags: forms, jquery

I have a loop that creates a small number of forms on a page.  Here is how the loop-creation looks like in PHP. This code is inside a loop:

```
echo '<form class="add_suggested_solution_comment"  method="post">';
echo '<p><textarea class="suggested_solution_comment" cols=65 rows=6 ></textarea></p>';
echo '<input type="hidden" class="problem_id" value="'.$problem_id.'" />';                                                  echo '<input type="hidden" class="suggestion_id" value="'.$suggestion_id.'" />';   
echo '<input type="hidden" class="solution_section_id" value="'.$solution_section_id.'" />'; 
echo '<p><input type="submit" class="button" value="Add Comment"></input></p>';             
echo '</form>';
```

And then I have the jQuery code that gets the values of the form fields like this:

```
$('.add_suggested_solution_comment').live('submit',function()
{   
    var problem_id = $('.problem_id').val();
    var comment = $(".suggested_solution_comment").val();   
    var solution_id = $('.suggestion_id').val();    
    var solution_section_id = $('.solution_section_id').val();      
        ...
```

And the problem is that if text is entered into the first textarea, it gets recognized by the line that gets the comment: var comment = $(".suggested_solution_comment").val();

But if any of the other textarea fields are entered, their values are not recognized by that line.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!!

Comment: People have been suggesting I use ids, but I think I am not clear on how to retrieve the value by id if I end up having n diff ids.  Any idea how that would work?

Comment: You're already supplying IDs in the PHP; use those IDs as a suffix to create an ID for each form field. Or do as I suggested and don't search the entire DOM, but the children of the form being submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the context argument of jQuery, like this:

```
$('.add_suggested_solution_comment').live('submit',function()
{   
    var $this = $(this);
    var problem_id = $('.problem_id', $this).val();
    var comment = $(".suggested_solution_comment", $this).val();   
    var solution_id = $('.suggestion_id', $this).val();    
    var solution_section_id = $('.solution_section_id', $this).val();      
    ...
```

That will only select the elements within the currently submitting form.

Comment: Not having tested this, I'll go out on a limb and say it's more on the money. It's not the lack of IDs bringing you down, GeekedOut, but lack of context. Without it, your function was only acting on the first matched element it found in the page.

Comment: @GeekedOut I don't actually care, but that's what I said.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in your answer. Props to @Dave Newton

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be better to explicitly identify the text area with an id, since you have a problem id you can use? Otherwise you're trying to get a single val() from a class selector with an arbitrary number of matches.

(The same thing applies to the other fields you're not identifying uniquely.)

You could, I suppose, find a matching child of the form element, rather than the entire DOM.

Answer (score 1):

... I'd suggest generating the texareas with IDs instead of classes and accessing them accordingly with jQuery, this way jQ won't get confused about which textarea it's dealing with.

Comment: I thought about ids, but if I have n differently id'd textareas, how do I know which one is clicked? Do I have like a switch statement or something like that? What would be a good way to get the value of the textarea which is entered if I have n diff ids it can be associated with?

Comment: generate the appropriate js code similarly to the way you create the textarea. So a php loop. For starters I'd create just the first one just to make sure that all works as expected and then move on to generating multiple texareas, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick thought: use id's to differentiate between inputs in the loops. Something like:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$something; $i++){
...
   echo '<input type="hidden" class="problem_id" id="problem_id_'.$i.'" value="'.$problem_id.'" />'; 
...
}
```

then you will be able to access those separately and empty fields on iteration x wont overwrite your inputs from beginning of the form.